# Display a partial view in an index page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making my first .NET MVC 4 application just to try it out. I have made an application wich is connected to MongoDB where you can store en retrive car data. Currently these are two different views. But I want them to become two different partial views, which I can display in one view. To do this, I started over with my application.

I have made an CarsController:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CarsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

I have made a CarsModel

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class InsertCarViewModel
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }
        public decimal DailyRentalFee { get; set; }
        public string DelimitedListOfCountries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have made the folder Cars for the Indexview and Shared for the partial views (_Create.cshtml).

My Index view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model.InsertCarViewModel)}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Partial view (_Create)

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCarViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>InsertCarViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Make)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Make)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Make)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DelimitedListOfCountries)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DelimitedListOfCountries)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DelimitedListOfCountries)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I can't see my partial view and I get an error.
What am I missing / doing wrong? Does my Index view need a Model?

Comment: post the error you are getting?

Comment: Please post your partial view code and the error...

Comment: there should also be semicolon `;` at the end of `Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model.InsertCarViewModel)` like this  `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model.InsertCarViewModel);}`

Comment: Your Index view also must need the header like in Partialview  "@model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCarViewModel " . Please go-through my code.

Comment: what is the model of Index view?

Comment: Hai I posted new answer too please gothrough it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do like this

Note: **Your Have to mention the namespace of model which you using the Index page.**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCarViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model)}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your partial view all must need to contain the same name space you passing

example :

```
 @model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCarViewModel
@{
    layout = null;
 }
<p> partial view</p>
```

Comment: Please try this you have to mention the mode in your view.

Comment: Please let me know if it is helps you

Comment: Yes this works, thank you! Now if I want to add another partial view to the same index view, can I just add another @model to the index page?

Comment: why define model in index, Op is not using model in index, `RenderAction()` is well suited in this case

Comment: No you can't able to able to add more then one @model in a single page. instead of it you can use any other class in your car class. Example: !st create a class like bikeClass in name of bike and thencreate a object for bikeclass in carclass. Then in your index view you can able to call bikeClass like @Model.bike( which you can use to pass to another partial view).

Comment: If you can't able to understand let me know, I will post some codes.

Comment: Some codes would be nice. Eventually I want to create a List partial view to also display on the index.

Comment: K. I will add another answer in few mins.

Answer (score 1):

Your Main View has no model defined, you could use [`RenderAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721274%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as it is more suitable here as you are create action:

```
<div>
    @{  Html.RenderAction("Create", "Cars"); } // first parameter action name,
                                        //   second controller name
</div>
```

or use `Html.Action()`:

```
<div>
     @Html.Action("Create", "Cars") // first parameter action name,
                                            //   second controller name

</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, maybe because I don't know what "Cares" is? Is this a better solution when you want to add multiple partial views to one index?

Comment: @bbvanee first parameter is action name and second is controller name, it was typo by me, instead of  **Cars** i wrote **Cares**

Answer (score 1):

Please Do Create class like below : I am taking yours as example.

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class InsertCarViewModel
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }
        public decimal DailyRentalFee { get; set; }
        public string DelimitedListOfCountries { get; set; }

        public List<InsertBikeViewModel> Bike { get; set; }
        public InsertCicyleViewModel Cicyle { get; set; }
    }

    public class InsertBikeViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class InsertCicyleViewModel
    {
        public string cicyleName { get; set; }
        public int cicyleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And your main Index must be like below

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCarViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_CreateBike", Model.Bike)
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_CreateCicyle", Model.Cicyle)
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in below code I am to show list of bikes in a Partial View.

Note : **I am give the  name as "_CreateBike" to below partial view, which should match with the one which I defined in Index view.**

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.InsertBikeViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

 @foreach ( var bikeItem in Model)
 {
    <div>  @bikeItem.Name </div>
    <div>  @bikeItem.Id </div>
 }


</body>
</html>
```

And your another partial view with Cicyle class.

Note : **I am give the  name as "_CreateCicyle" toto below partial view which should match with the one which I defined in Index view.**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.InsertCicyleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>  @cicyleItem .cicyleName </div>
<div>  @cicyleItem .cicyleId </div>
```

Comment: So would it be more orderly to make a new class with `public InsertCarViewModel Car` `public InsertCycleViewModel Cycle` etc instead of putting those inside the InsertCarViewModel

Comment: Yes, Then only you can able to use the model in partial view as its own class

Comment: i'm still trying to make your sample work. And it sort of works, but my Partial views don't do anything. When the `create` view was a normal view, it passed data to the database. But now it is a partial view, it doesn't do this, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Html.Partial`, no need for render partial here.

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_Create", Model.InsertCarViewModel)
</div>
```